# Dreamweaver CS6 - Restarts my PC (even on first runtime)

Tags: dreamweaver, runtime-error

I have dell OptiPlex 755 PC, I have downloaded & installed the Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 from [adobe](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=dreamweaver&loc=en_us).

After installation when i run the software it just restarts my pc after a couple of seconds and even doesn't show any error message.
it is a quick restart no waiting time. i use windows XP Professional edition version 2002 service pack 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer probably encountered a STOP error and restarted. STOP errors cause BSODS (Blue Screens Of Death) because they are very serious and cause the whole operating system to crash. Windows XP by default restarts your computer instead of displaying the blue screen which will tell you what happened.

To learn how to enable the display of blue screens in Windows XP go [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/ht/disautorestart.htm).